# Hipchat-Confluence Integration on something other than a space

Tags: confluence, hipchat

I know that you can integrate Atlassian Confluence spaces to Hipchat rooms and my company's Atlassian admin has enabled this integration. However, I'd like to integrate based on changes to a given page or any of its descendants, not on a space. Can I do this?

I cant define a new space because I don't have authorization to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Integration between HipChat and Confluence is based on the space. However, you are able to configure it and adjust the notifications during the configurations. For example, you can manage to get Page Update or Page Create notifications in your chat room if you check the checkbox during the integration. Take a look at this [documents](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/use-hipchat-and-confluence-together-678561679.html) as it contains the screen shot and details about the feature.